# @@SPID equivalent in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, t-sql, equivalent

Is there an equivalent to @@SPID in Postgres or any other way to identify different connections to the same client process connected to the databases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pg_backend_pid()`

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html

Comment: Thanks, I thought actually that Postgres has some other way of differentiating between connections but this should suffice.

Comment: @ax1mx2: why do you think you need a different way? Taking the the architectural differences into account, SQL Server's spid is *exactly* the same thing as Postgres' backend PID

Comment: I suppose you're right, thanks. I wish I could read more about such structural differences between Postgres and MS SQL Server.